# Using "isTRUE" for compare vectors?

Tags: r

Please, look this simple code:

```
> x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
> data = matrix(x,nrow = 3, ncol = 3) 
> v1 = colMeans(data)
> v1
[1] 2 5 8
> v2 = apply(data, 2, mean)
> v2
[1] 2 5 8
> identical(v1, v2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(v1, v2)
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(v1 == v2)
[1] FALSE
```

"isTRUE"  show the comparison as FALSE, that's means it's impossible to use it for compare vectors?

Comment: You wanted either `all(v1==v2)` or `identical(v1,v2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct.

```
> isTRUE
function (x) 
identical(TRUE, x)
<bytecode: 0x000000002824e1c0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`isTRUE` is meant to be used to check if something is identical to TRUE.  A vector of TRUE values isn't the same thing as TRUE.  Maybe you want to use `all`?

```
> all(c(TRUE, TRUE))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

From `?isTRUE`

> isTRUE(x) is an abbreviation of identical(TRUE, x), and so is true if
>   and only if x is a length-one logical vector whose only element is
>   TRUE and which has no attributes (not even names).

You could:

```
isTRUE(all(v1 == v2))
```

Comment: A key point is the test for "identicality" of the attributes by way of `identical`. In this case it is the lack of attributes that is being tested but in many instances users of `identical` get tripped up because inconsequential attributes are not the same in two objects. (I don't think that is the "answer" here, but I do think it was worthwhile mentioning it.)